# how to link a html file for tabs - Angular 2

Tags: html, dom, typescript, angular, nativescript

I have implemented files such as '***auth.ts***' and '***auth.html***', etc. And I have a main page (***menu.html*** and ***menu.ts***) where tabs appear. I want to link, for example, auth.html file for one tab, so that one tab will be for logging in, and another tab will be for an another action and so on. Is there a way to do that with NativeScript?

So far the main page looks like this:

[image]

And now I want to add actions for each tab. Do i have to implement them in 'menu' files, or there is a way to link(call) html/ts files with others?

Comment: You could read more about page navigation in NativeScript Angular2 docs - http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/navigation-angular.html . In regard to the question you could also review this sample project- https://github.com/tsonevn/NGNavigationRtConf.git

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Angular 2 Routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

in your `app.component.ts` you will have a section like so

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from '...';
import { AuthComponent} from '...';
import { MenuComponent} from '...';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  viewProviders: [...],
  templateUrl: '...',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    HomeComponent],        
  })
@Routes([
  {
    path: '/',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: AuthComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/menu',
    component: MenuComponent
  }
])
```

Then inside your `app.component.html`add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`